# PyCharm -> Project (не работает Show Members)

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains

В IDE PyCharm не работает настройка во вкладке Project (Show Members). Вкладка Tool Window -> Project (установлена в Project), но тем не менее файлы не получается раскрыть и получить их class и methods. Возможно нужно какое-то допольнительно условие?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая версия Пичарма? У меня эта фича работает (даже не знал что такое есть), версия PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2 (Build #PC-172.3317.103, built on July 25, 2017)

Comment: У меня 2017.3.4 (Professional Edition)